# jQuery Validation, multiple form ids for same function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Hi have two forms with the exact same validation rules, but different ids that I'd like to combine into just one function.  How can I do that?

```
var validator = $("#ValidateForm1").validate({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":radio") )
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
    else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
        error.appendTo ( element.next() );
    else
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
}       
});

var validator = $("#validateForm2").validate({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":radio") )
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
    else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
        error.appendTo ( element.next() );
    else
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
}       
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the validator variable (which you're re-defining, so it appears you don't), just use a multiple selector:

```
$("#validateForm1, #validateForm2").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":radio") )
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
    else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
        error.appendTo ( element.next() );
    else
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
  }       
});
```

Or, if you have a lot of forms like this, just give them a class and like this:

```
<form id="validateForm1" class="myFormClass"></form>
<form id="validateForm2" class="myFormClass"></form>
....
<form id="validateFormX" class="myFormClass"></form>
```

And a selector like this:

```
$(".myFormClass").validate({
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't work because submitting one form will validate all forms. You could override the submit and pass the form to validate, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757057/jquery-validate-not-working-on-multiple-form

Comment: Just tried the first solution and it doesn't work either, validate only takes one selector.

Comment: Tried the first solution, and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the formId as a variable

```
var myFormId = "ValidateForm1"; // e.g. get the form id by using javascript

....

var validator = $("#"+ myFormId).validate({
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":radio") )
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
    else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
        error.appendTo ( element.next() );
    else
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
}       
});
```