# jquery validate not working on multiple form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

Jquery validate works fine for webpage with single form. However, when i call the form through jquery and display in jquery-ui dialog the validation does not work anymore. I am calling the contact us from from the main page. In the main page another form exist use for searching. The code is given below.

```
$("#contactus").live('click',function(){
            $.get('/gordon/contacts/sendemail',function(result){
            $('#popupinfo').html(result);   
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "title", 'Contact Us' );
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "height",'auto');
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "width",650);    
            $("#popupinfo").dialog('open');
       });
    });
    $("#popupinfo").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
  show: "blind",
  hide: "explode",
      modal: true
   });
$('.submit').live('click', function () {
          var form = $("#ContactSendemailForm");
          $(form).validate();
    });
```

EDIT:

```
 $('.submit').live('click', function () {
         $(".validates").each(function() {
             $(this).validate();
            });

    });
```

Where validates is class of the form. But it still does not work.

EDIT: The HTML code
The page from where i call the contact us form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate-1.9.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#contactus").live('click',function(){
            $.get('/gordon/shows/send',function(result){
            $('#popupinfo').html(result);   
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "title", 'Contact Us' );
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "height",'auto');
            $( "#popupinfo" ).dialog( "option", "width",650);    
            $("#popupinfo").dialog('open');
            });
        });
       $("#popupinfo").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            modal: true
       });

        $('.submit').live('click', function () {
            $('.validates').each(function() {
                $(this).validate();
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- for searching contents from the website -->
    <form action="/gordon/searchresults" id="search" class="search-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
        </div>
        <input name="data[q]" class="search" id="searchtext" type="text"/>
        <input value="" type="submit" class="button" />
    </form>

    <div id="popupinfo"></div>

    <a href="#" id="contactus" onclick="return false;">Contact us</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The Contact us form

```
<style type="text/css">
    label { width: 10em; float: left; }
    label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
    p { clear: both; }
    .submit { margin-left: 12em; }
    em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>

    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Contact',array('class'=>'validates'));
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<p>' . $this->Form->input('name',array('label' => 'Name','class'=>'required')) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $this->Form->input('email',array('label' => 'Email','class'=>'required email')) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $this->Form->input('subject',array('label' => 'Subject','class'=>'required')) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $this->Form->input('message',array('rows'=>3,'label' => 'Message','class'=>'required')) . '</p>';

        echo '<p><input id="sendmail" value="" type="submit" class="submit" /></p>';
        echo '</fieldset>';

        echo $this->Form->end();
     ?>
```

Update: The code generated by Cakephp for the Contact Form

```
<form action="/gordon/contacts/sendemail" controller="contacts" id="ContactSendemailForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div><fieldset><p>
    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="ContactName">Name</label>
        <input name="data[Contact][name]" class="required" maxlength="60" type="text" value="" id="ContactName"/>
    </div></p>
    <p><div class="input text required">
        <label for="ContactEmail">Email</label>
        <input name="data[Contact][email]" class="required email" maxlength="60" type="text" value="" id="ContactEmail"/>
    </div></p>
    <p><div class="input text required">
    <label for="ContactSubject">Subject</label>
    <input name="data[Contact][subject]" class="required" maxlength="100" type="text" value="" id="ContactSubject"/>
    </div></p>
    <p><div class="input textarea required">
        <label for="ContactMessage">Message</label>
        <textarea name="data[Contact][message]" rows="3" class="required" cols="30" id="ContactMessage"></textarea>
        </div></p>
    <p><input id="sendmail" value="" type="submit" class="submit" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your only getting a single form -></strike>

`var form = $("#ContactSendemailForm");`

this selector gets an element with the ID of `ContactSendemailForm`

you need to get each form to validate() then validate it - do the forms have classes ? if so do this

```
$(".classofform").each(function() {
     $(this).validate();
});
```

This calls the `validate()` method on each of the jQuery objects - the selector returns a collection of DOM elements with the class `classofform`

[Docs for each()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

**Updated**

Following the comments attached to this answer I think that my answer was misleading ... I thought that you wanted to validate both forms at the same time .. now, however, I know you don't ...

First off some basic explanation .. the live() method in jQuery is used to listen to events on elements that are not yet present on the DOM - you dont need to use this when the object is present at page load ...

You have a page with a form already present :

```
<form action="/gordon/searchresults" id="search" class="search-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>
    <input name="data[q]" class="search" id="searchtext" type="text"/>
    <input value="" type="submit" class="button" />
</form>

<div id="popupinfo"></div>

<a href="#" id="contactus" onclick="return false;">Contact us</a>
```

This has an id of `search` so to validate this form on submit do this :

```
$('search').submit(function() {
   $(this).validate();
)}
```

Docs for the [submit() method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Then to ensure you correctly validate the contact-us (via the popup) form you can do this :

```
$('#contactform').live('submit', function() {
   $(this).validate();
)}
```

The use of the live() function (on() should be used in jQuery 1.7+) means that it will work whether the contactform element is present at load or not.

One last thing to note is that the code that executes on elements present on load should be contained in the following function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // code here
)}
```

This ensures the DOM elements are ready before being manipulated

**Update 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate-1.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate-1.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

The core jQuery library should be loaded before any plugins

Docs :

- [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your suggestion but still it does not work.

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih can you please add your HTML to your question ... or create an example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have uploaded the HTML content. I am using CakePHP. Looking forward for your help

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih there is only one form with the class `.validates` so it will only validate one form !!!

Comment: Even if I remove the class name from the form and call validate through $("#ContactSendemailForm").validate(); It still does not call. When i don't have the search form it works fine. Also when i use the same code in a page where there is a single form it works smoothly. Am confused!

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih is the click firing ? try using `console.log()` or `alert()` to check

Comment: Yes the click is firing. Tested with alert(). alert($('#ContactSendemailForm').closest('form').attr('id')); also shows the form ID

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih i think the code in my answer doesnt do what you want it to do anyway - it will validate both forms on the press of the submit button - i think you want to validate only the form in question ..why not setup a click listener for each for and validate the form concerned

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry, am still not very fluent with web programming. I didn't get  what you mean. Did u mean create click listener for the submit button of the contact form?

Comment: the click listener for the search forms work, but for ContactSearchemailForm it does not trigger. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. The submit listener is now triggered ( tested with alert() ) however, $(this).validate() is  not executing

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih I think i have just realised why !!!! you need to include jQuery js library before any plugins ... i think you have the validate plugin listed before the jQuery library ! <- simple as that ....

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Now the validate() function gets executed (tested with alert() before and after the validate() ). However, validation does not seem to be working :(

Comment: Are you using this -> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation have you tried their examples ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Infact for a single form it works like a charm. I have updated the code generated by CakePHP. I can't seem to understand why no error shows or validate() not getting executed.

Comment: Try adding the validate() method to the bottom of the form - run it when the form is loaded - it seems that it should be executed on load no on submit

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience and help. It finally worked. Am very grateful to you. :)

Comment: @GordonNongkynrih no probs - sorry it took so long :-)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
form.validate();
```

And not

```
$(form).validate();
```

You've already included the `$()` part when you set the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. tried your method but still does not get executed. It works only for a single form